# Google Calendar - SyncToken is missing in API response

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I don't see `nextSyncToken` in the response. I followed the doc(https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/sync) and paginated using `nextPageToken` but I couldn't see the `nextSyncToken` on the last page.

API Used: `GET /calendars/primary/events?maxResults=10&singleEvents=true&pageToken=********`

I don't know whether if I miss anything here. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Try this API for the LIST method](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) from the browser? Also, have you tried it without using the `maxResults` and `singleEvents` parameters, just to test if that is the code's issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have seen from the response link on the other answer comment that you are using `orderBy` on the request.

This is why the `nextSyncToken` is not showing up.

As mentioned on the documentation on [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) -> Parameters -> `syncToken`:

> Token obtained from the nextSyncToken field returned on the last page of results from the previous list request. It makes the result of this list request contain only entries that have changed since then. All events deleted since the previous list request will always be in the result set and it is not allowed to set showDeleted to False.
> There are several query parameters that cannot be specified together with nextSyncToken to ensure consistency of the client state.
>
> These are:
>
> - iCalUID
> - **orderBy**
> - privateExtendedProperty
> - q
> - sharedExtendedProperty
> - timeMin
> - timeMax
> - updatedMin
>
> If the syncToken expires, the server will respond with a 410 GONE response code and the client should clear its storage and perform a full synchronization without any syncToken.
> Learn more about incremental synchronization.
> Optional. The default is to return all entries.

You should remove the `orderBy` from the request to get the `syncToken`

Comment: Gotcha... By removing `orderBy` parameter I could able to receive the `nextSyncToken`. Thanks @Kessy

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide the response from gcalendar API? It's hard to say more without detail information. I event don't know which language are you using.

1. Try to use a vendor library to sort that out:

a) https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient (for PHP)

b) https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-calendar (for JavaScript)

and/or

2. Try to use alternative endpoint: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events`.

Comment: @Dharman/@Juljan
Since the response was huge I'm unable to attach it. Use this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kOQc4KIGCFUYoU1DkIezJUlVqrHObvMO/view?usp=sharing) to see the response.
I tried in the postman application and I tried with both the endpoints `calendars/primary/events` & `calendars/calendarId/events` but end up with the same result.